# Strange “Verizon Mobile” volume mounted on Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)

Tags: macos, filesystems, mount, debug, osx-yosemite

After recently installing Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite), I find this Verizon Mobile volume mounted even though I don’t use Verizon at all (currently subscribed to AT&T) and never installed anything related to Verizon I can think of. The volume is empty and I can’t seem to even eject it.

Could this be a bug in Yosemite, symptom of a 0-day, or other strange anomaly?

More info about the volume:

[image]

Comment: Upvoting out of curiosity.

Comment: What kind of PC/laptop are you running? Does it have a built-in 3G/4G/LTE/Other modem/card/adapter?

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `diskutil list`, `mount`, and `ls -l /Volumes`?

Comment: I rebooted my computer last night and now that strange Veizon volume is not there anymore. Strangely enough, when I shut down my computer last night, it froze with a black screen and the usual rotating circular Apple animation. I let it sit there for like 2 hours and it was just jammed there so I had to force a shutdown by holding the power button.

Comment: I have thew newest Macbook Air 13", top of the line (Apple's refurbished store has a decent deal, haha). No strange 3G/4G/LTE/other-telecom-stuff in there to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well.

Then I realized that I had left my hotspot plugged into my USB hub (was just in “charging mode” and not tethered). Unplugged it an Viola!

So there is a small volume on the hotspot formated in HFS and partitioned using a CD partitioning scheme. Odd.

```
/dev/disk6
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:        CD_partition_scheme                        *410.1 MB   disk6
   1:     Apple_partition_scheme                         357.1 MB   disk6s0
   2:        Apple_partition_map                         1.0 KB     disk6s0s1
   3:                  Apple_HFS Verizon Mobile          7.5 MB     disk6s0s2
```